# Dogtag PKI "/usr/share/pki/common-ui" is missing

Tags: java, tomcat, centos, webserver, pki

I am using Dogtag PKI 11.4.2 on CentOS 9
I am facing an issue where Tomcat can not find the static css/image files as the GUI for dogtag is actually missing!

[image]

This  is the command i am using for installing the PKI:

```
sudo dnf install pki-server pki-tools pki-ca 389-ds-base -y
```

I tried looking up the common-ui folder on the internet but i could not find it anywhere :(